# How to bring back old style window docking in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I recently started using Eclipse Juno (4.2) on Fedora Linux.  In prior versions of eclipse I could simply click and drag a source file name to the edge of the screen and split my window with the mouse.  Now when I click+drag Eclipse brings up some green outlines and I can't figure out how to accept the change without hitting Enter on the keyboard.  Does anyone know if its possible to bring back the prior behavior where the mouse can do everything?
Thanks!

Edit: Sounds like there may be a bug in Eclipse, at least when using Fedora 17 64-bit.

Comment: I have this bug on Ubuntu 12.04, and even Enter doesn't help. However I discovered that the green border is actually a separate window (event to alt-tab), and so I can "switch" to it and press Alt-F4 to close it!

Comment: Worse now on Fedora 18 + Juno 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you have a green rectangle that represent the area that will be occupied when you release the mouse button, however the procedure still the same you have to drag the editor and drop the editor in the desired area ...

Just move the mouse with the left button clicked and you will notice that the green rectangles change and when you have a rectangle with double borders you can release the mouse button ...

Comment: This is still a buggy at least on my system (ubuntu 12.04, openjdk7) it gets confused and it can't seem to keep up (then green rectangles keeps on moving around after I stopped moving the mouse). I fond that when it eventually gets to where I want it I can click any where to apply the move.

Comment: I have to type enter on the keyboard.  Releasing the mouse won't make it work.  I wasn't sure if this was expected, but it sounds like a bug.

Comment: On Fedora 18 with Juno 4.2.2 things have gotten worse. Previously the green rectangle thing worked somewhat smoothly; now the entire screen gets garbled/out of whack when dragging and dropping from one editor pane to the other, very distracting. It does "work" but it's a truly f-ed up user experience.